# Mask Textfield component in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a mask in a TextField component, but im without success.

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758998/how-can-i-mask-my-material-ui-textfield) but not worked. I tried every way but seems to not work anymore.

I tried to [follow the instructions given in docs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) but they use the Input component and this component is breaking my design.

Anyone knows a way to mask the TextField component? I'm using material-ui 1.0.0-beta.24

Comment: Could you provide some of the code you're using? Also, how does the `Input` component break your design?

Comment: @julesDupont When I use the input component it gets different from the TextField component visually speaking. As you can see is [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/6G42zAk.png).

The code is really necessary? if it is, i'll post. but it's just a bunch of Grids and TextField inputs

Comment: There's probably no need for code - I just wasn't clear about what you meant when you said the `Input` affected formatting. I've given you a solution that should allow you to use a `TextField` with a mask.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `InputProps` to set the mask directly on a `TextField` component. For example, suppose your desired mask is represented by the `TextMaskCustom` component. Then, instead of applying it to an `Input` directly, you can apply it to your `TextField` using the `InputProps` like so:

```
<TextField
  id="maskExample"
  label="Mask Example"
  className={classes.textField}
  margin="normal"
  InputProps={{
    inputComponent: TextMaskCustom,
    value: this.state.textmask,
    onChange: this.handleChange('textmask'),
  }}
/>
```

This works because a `TextField` is actually a [wrapper around an `Input` component](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/#advanced-configuration) (with some other things mixed in). The `InputProps` prop of the `TextField` gives you access to the internal `Input`, so you can set the mask that way while preserving the styling of the `TextField` component.

Here's a full working example adapted from the [demos in the docs](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/):

```
import React from 'react';
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  input: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const TextMaskCustom = (props) => {
  const { inputRef, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <MaskedInput
      {...other}
      ref={inputRef}
      mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
      placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
      showMask
    />
  );
}

TextMaskCustom.propTypes = {
  inputRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

class FormattedInputs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    textmask: '(1  )    -    ',
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <TextField
          id="maskExample"
          label="Mask Example"
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
          InputProps={{
            inputComponent: TextMaskCustom,
            value:this.state.textmask,
            onChange: this.handleChange('textmask'),
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

FormattedInputs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(FormattedInputs);
```

Comment: How to pass custom prefix to inputComponent as props. For instance, if I want to change the currency sign for inputComponent in NumberFormated Type

Comment: ```
InputProps={{
    inputComponent: TextMaskCustom,
    inputProps: {...} 
  }}
```
adding the (lowerCase) inputProps lets you pass in props for use in your inputComponent.

Comment: If you're using the newer Material UI (imported with '@material-ui/core', then you will get this error:
"Material-UI: you have provided a `inputComponent` to the input component
that does not correctly handle the `inputRef` prop.
Make sure the `inputRef` prop is called with a HTMLInputElement."

To fix this, change the `ref=` line in `TextMaskCustom` for:
```ref={ref => {
    inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
}}```