# Thousand separator in React Mui TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield

I'm trying to add Thousand separator to my mui-textField value, knowing that I already made digit separation. My code looks like this:

```
<TextField
                    size='small'
                    label='Total Cotisations Encaissées'
                    value={
                        totalEncaissement
                         ?.toFixed(modeMO)
                        ?.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$& ") || 0
                    }
                    variant='outlined'
                    fullWidth
                    type={"number"}
                />
            </Grid>
```

The field doesn't display anything when I add replace, but works totally fine with toFixed only.
Please could somebody help?

Comment: no one wants to help?

Comment: I  found that the problem was from type={"number"}.thanks me

Comment: Feel free to add an answer that answers your own question, and accept that answer here

Answer (score 6):

According to [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) you can use `react-number-format` package to add a thousand separators to the `TextField` component.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the documentation

Comment: I am trying a price input. How to allow decimal input along with masking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758998/how-can-i-mask-my-material-ui-textfield
@asifsaho