# How to implement text mask in MUI Textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, mask, imaskjs

So I want to implement a mask to my mui Textfields for price and credit card number, but idk how. For example I want the price texfield to start with "$", and the card number to be separated with "-". I've tried the things from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758998/how-can-i-mask-my-material-ui-textfield) , but it doesn't work. Here is one of my textfields:

```
<TextField
  required
  className="form__input"
  id="price"
  name="price"
  value={formData.price}
  label="Ticket Price"
  variant="outlined"
  type="number"
  onChange={(event) => eventHandleChange(event)}
  error={!/(^$)|(^[+]?\d+([.]\d+)?$)/.test(formData.price)}
  helperText={
    !/(^$)|(^[+]?\d+([.]\d+)?$)/.test(formData.price) &&
    validations.positiveNumbersOnly
  }
/>
```

Comment: You can use third-party libraries to format an input. You have to provide a custom implementation of the <input> element with the inputComponent property. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries

Comment: Thranks @MileMijatović